# how to auto format E501 line too long (89 > 88 characters) in pre-commit?

Tags: python, pre-commit, python-black, ruff

I have below .pre-commit-config.yaml file.

```
default_language_version:
  python: python3.10
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks:
      - id: check-yaml
      - id: end-of-file-fixer
      - id: trailing-whitespace
      - id: check-byte-order-marker
  - repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
    rev: 5.12.0
    hooks:
      - id: isort
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 23.7.0
    hooks:
      - id: black
  - repo: https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff-pre-commit
    rev: 'v0.0.287'
    hooks:
      - id: ruff
        args: [--fix, --exit-non-zero-on-fix]
```

I have demo.py python file where few lines are exceeding max-length 88 chars, in that case pre-commit only giving
`E501 line too long (89 > 88 characters)` error instead of re-formatting that line.

Is there any way we can auto-fix such issues?

Comment: what is your content for ruff.toml or black.toml

Comment: I have not created ruff.toml file. Do we need this while using ruff?

Comment: try follow this article https://datawookie.dev/blog/2022/09/enforcing-style-in-a-python-project/'

Answer (score 4):

See [the Ruff documentation](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/faq/#is-the-ruff-linter-compatible-with-black):

> Note that Ruff and Black treat `line-length` enforcement a little differently. Black makes a best-effort attempt to adhere to the line-length, but avoids automatic line-wrapping in some cases (e.g., within comments). Ruff, on the other hand, will flag rule `E501` for any line that exceeds the line-length setting. As such, if `E501` is enabled, Ruff can still trigger line-length violations even when Black is enabled.

IOW, no.

Since you're using Black, you can just disable the Ruff E501 rule; Black will keep your lines under its line-length (as well as it can).

Alternately, you can try [the brand spanking new `ruff-format` hook](https://astral.sh/blog/the-ruff-formatter) for formatting your code and skip Black:

```
  - repo: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-pre-commit
    rev: v0.1.3
    hooks:
      - id: ruff
        args: [--fix, --exit-non-zero-on-fix]
      - id: ruff-format
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is NO. And it is also logical because if a formatter break your string into two parts randomly(?!), it might cause issues in the code itself.

So, there are two things you can do.

1. Use f-string (or multiple lines of string) and put the long line of string into multiple lines.
   For example, instead of the below string,
   `'this is very long line of text, very very long .........'`

use

```
('this is very long line of'
'text, very very long .........'
)
```

Edit:

Even more pythonic way can be (for better visibility)-

```
(
    'this is very long line of'
    'text, very very long .........'
)
```

2. You can also keep as it is in the long line and add comment to ignore the error. Just add `# noqa: E501` as inline comment.